# Which technology ( SQL/NoSQL) to use for real-time data aggregation

Tags: nosql, aggregate-functions

I need to design a near real-time system where documents  ( with fields:id,keywords,timestamp ) are getting added to the system. The requirement is to  get top-k keywords from the documents added to the system in last x minutes. The typical document addition rate is around 100 documents/sec, which may increase in the future ( hence technology should be horizontally scalable ).

I am thinking of using solr-facets ( with sharding ) to generate the top-k keywords, where I am a bit concerned about the high writes/sec for solr. Another option is to use Cassandra, but not sure how it will scale for range queries ( to compute aggregates ), as OrderPreservingPartitioner could make it difficult to distribute the load.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a [Complex Event Processing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_event_processing) problem, not a database or search problem.  You don't care so much about keeping the data as you do about getting keyword trends or something similar in realtime. Some vendors/libraries that you'd want to look at are (with many omissions):

**Microsoft/.NET:**

[StreamInsight](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/solutions-technologies/business-intelligence/complex-event-processing.aspx) - Microsoft's CEP offering

[Reactive Extensions for .NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609) - extensions to .NET for stream processing

**Java:**

[Esper](http://esper.codehaus.org/) - very popular OSS stream processing library

[Storm](https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm) - stream processing on Hadoop, likely to scale to extremely large data volumes

**3rd Party / Proprietary (Won't comment on these, don't know enough about them):**

[StreamBase](http://www.streambase.com/)

[Aleri](http://www.sybase.com/products/financialservicessolutions/complex-event-processing)

Comment: just curious, what could be the issue with solr-facets ?

Comment: Nothing wrong with it at all.  It just doesn't seem like the right tool for the job.  Facets, AFAIK (and Grant Ingersoll could correct me here) lets you drill into search results by attributes of the search, which is great for things like product search on websites.  You just care about the last few minutes of events- after that you discard the old stuff.

Answer (score 0):

use sql and nosql at the same time.

use sql for queries and use nosql for complex datas.

write x2 code. and solve every problem with their needs in mind.